# How to change directory in shell script?

Tags: shell, expect

I have written below script to get access of SSH:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn ssh 123456 -p 2222
expect "password:"
send "foopassword\r"
interact
```

`#!/usr/bin/expect -f` only works for me now as we will have to automate the password entry as well.

later after logging, trying to do `cd /xyz/directory`, but that's not working.

Given try referring to related posts and stored the path as alias inside Bash file, but still no luck.

https://askubuntu.com/questions/481715/why-doesnt-cd-work-in-a-shell-script

How to `cd` to some path and do `ls` and `read` the content after ssh logging? Is it possible to do from Bash scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, after you authenticate, you will expect to see your shell prompt. Then you can send whatever shell commands you want before you take control back with "interact":

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

spawn ssh 123456 -p 2222
expect "password:"
send "foopassword\r"
expect -re {\$ $}        ;# shell prompt regex: prompt ends with "$" and space.

send "cd /foo/bar/baz\r"
expect -re {\$ $}

send "/bin/ls -1\r"
expect -re {/bin/ls -1\r\n(.*)\r\n.*\$ $}

set file_list $expect_out(1,string)
puts "found these files:\n$file_list"

interact
```

Extracting command output from the data stream from the ssh connection is one of the painful parts of automating ssh. Here, we send the `ls` command, but to capture the command output, we need a complicated regex:

```
expect -re {/bin/ls -1\r\n(.*)\r\n.*\$ $}
# ..........\\    #1    //\\ #2 //\\#3//
```

1. `/bin/ls -1\r\n` -- matches the command we just sent followed by CRLF.

   - since the terminal echos the commands we type, expect will send it back for processing, and we have to deal with it.
   - expect always sends back `\r\n` for newlines
2. `(.*)\r\n` -- matches the actual command output followed by the newline that precedes your prompt

   - `.*` will match "internal" newlines in the command output. This part is captured for later use.
3. `.*\$ $` -- matches the prompt.

If you have customized your prompt, you may need to adjust the patterns accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your wonderful answer, ill test the code and accept your answer in a short while. Mean while i tried with the `expect "$" send -- "echo testing... \r"` is taking a longer time than expected even after $ prompt has come. Tried setting timeout to 0 and -1 at top of the file, but still no luck on this.

Comment: your expect -re returning fast response :) thanks @glenn jackman

Comment: When developing an expect script, always add `exp_internal 1` to see why your pattern do or do not match. Then take that line out when you put the code into production.

Comment: it will be great if u can breif this: `expect -re {/bin/ls -1\r\n(.*)\r\n.*\$ $}` :-)

Comment: is it possible to access the $file_list variable after exit because local machine needs that details.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to list the contents of a directory you do not need to cd to the directory first, just

ls xyz/directory

Comment: Have you had a look at this link, I think it is something similar to what you are trying to achieve:
[expect script ssh example tutorial](https://www.journaldev.com/1405/expect-script-ssh-example-tutorial)

Comment: referred and it is similar so far what we have achieved. But after login, need to do ls which is not working and it wont hold such contents as well